# Getting Ecto to pass foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, elixir, ecto

I'm working with Ecto (with Postgres) for the first time and I have the following two schemas (both somewhat simplified):

```
defmodule RailroadServer.Database.RailroadSystem do
  @moduledoc """
  Schema for an entire railroad system.
  """
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias RailroadServer.Database

  schema "railroad_systems" do
    field :railroad_system_name, :string
    has_many :depos, Database.Depo
  end

  @fields ~w(railroad_system_name)a

  def changeset(data, params \\ %{}) do
    data
    |> cast(params, @fields)
    |> validate_required([:railroad_system_name])
    |> validate_length(:railroad_system_name, max: 50)
  end
end
```

```
defmodule RailroadServer.Database.Depo do
  @moduledoc """
  Schema for a node that stores trains.
  """
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias RailroadServer.Database

  schema "depos" do
    field :capacity, :integer
    field :depo_uuid, :string
    field :depo_name, :string
    belongs_to :railroad_system, Database.RailroadSystem
  end

  @fields ~w(capacity depo_uuid depo_name)a

  def changeset(data, params \\ %{}) do
    data
    |> cast(params, @fields)
    |> validate_required([:capacity, :depo_uuid, :depo_name])
    |> validate_number(:capacity, greater_than: 0)
    |> validate_length(:depo_name, max: 50)
    |> validate_length(:depo_uuid, max: 50)
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:railroad_system_id)
  end
end
```

Based on these migrations:

```
defmodule RailroadServer.Database.Repo.Migrations.CreateRailroadSystems do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:railroad_systems) do
      add :railroad_system_name, :varchar, null: false, size: 50
    end

    create unique_index("railroad_systems", [:railroad_system_name])
  end
end
```

```
defmodule RailroadServer.Database.Repo.Migrations.CreateDepos do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:depos) do
      add :railroad_system_id, references("railroad_systems"), null: false
      add :depo_uuid, :varchar, size: 50, null: false
      add :depo_name, :varchar, size: 50, null: false
      add :capacity, :integer, null: false
    end

    create index("depos", [:railroad_system_id])
    create index("depos", [:depo_uuid], unique: true)
    create index("depos", [:depo_name], unique: true)
  end
end
```

Which I'm constructing with the following code:

```
  def insert_railway_system(system_name, depos) do
    cs = %RailroadSystem{}
    |> RailroadSystem.changeset(%{railroad_system_name: system_name})
    |> put_assoc(:depos, create_depos(depos))

    if cs.valid? do
      Repo.insert(cs)
    else
      {:error, cs}
    end
  end

  _ = """
  Uses a list of depo nodes to construct a list of depo changeset.
  """
  defp create_depos(depos) do
    Enum.map(depos, fn(depo) -> Depo.changeset(%Depo{}, depo) end)
  end
```

However, when I run this function (with data that produces a valid changeset), I get a NULL column error because the foreign key for the railway system in the depo struct doesn't exist. How do I make sure that Ecto passes that foreign key?

The output:

```
19:06:07.401 [debug] QUERY OK db=0.8ms
begin []

19:06:07.406 [debug] QUERY OK db=0.6ms
INSERT INTO "railroad_systems" ("railroad_system_name") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id" ["test Can insert railway system"]

19:06:07.409 [debug] QUERY ERROR db=2.7ms
INSERT INTO "depos" ("capacity","depo_name","depo_uuid") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" [23, "A depo", "d387a91b-db77-4758-87ed-9951d5c2de8a"]

19:06:07.410 [debug] QUERY OK db=0.1ms
rollback []


  1) test Can insert railway system (RailroadServer.DatabaseTest)
     apps/railroad_server/test/railroad_server/database_test.exs:9
     ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "railroad_system_id" violates not-null constraint

         table: depos
         column: railroad_system_id

     Failing row contains (3, null, d387a91b-db77-4758-87ed-9951d5c2de8a, A depo, 23).
     stacktrace:
       (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:621: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.raise_sql_call_error/1
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:649: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:262: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:927: Ecto.Association.BelongsTo.on_repo_change/5
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:413: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/7
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1948: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:392: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:811: Ecto.Repo.Schema.process_parents/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:242: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:662: Ecto.Association.Has.on_repo_change/5
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:432: anonymous fn/8 in Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/7
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1948: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:428: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/7
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1948: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:392: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:837: Ecto.Repo.Schema.process_children/5
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:914: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.wrap_in_transaction/6
       (ecto_sql) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:890: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.checkout_or_transaction/4
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1415: DBConnection.run_transaction/4
       (railroad_server) lib/railroad_server/database.ex:61: RailroadServer.Database.insert_railway_system/4
```

Versions:
Elixir - 1.9.0
Ecto - 3.17
Postgrex - 0.14.3
Prosgres - 11.4

Comment: `lib/railroad_server/database.ex:61: RailroadServer.Database.insert_railway_system/4`--Where is that?  You posted an `insert_railway_system/2`

Comment: I've removed some code to simplify the function.  There are two more sets of children (passed via two lists, like depos) associations  in the actual struct, with the same setup.  But it tries to insert depos first and fails on that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

When I try an insert with identical code as in your `insert_railway_system()`, I do not get a `NULL column error`.

My schemas are similar. The only significant difference in my code is in the changeset where I have the constraint:

```
|> assoc_constraint()
```

instead of:

```
|> foreign_key_constraint()
```

But I changed my code to try the `foreign_key_constraint()`, leaving the argument the same, which is equivalent to your `:railroad_system`, and the insert still worked. The insert also worked when I did the equivalent of `foreign_key_constraint(:railroad_system_id)`.  In fact, if I use `foreign_key_constraint(:hello_world)`, the insert still works, so as far as I can tell, the second argument to `foreign_key_constraint()` is ignored, which is puzzling.  I even did `mix ecto.reset`, which deletes the repo/database, recreates the repo/database, then executes the migrations, which creates the tables in the repo/database, and I got the same results.

My "create_depos" migration has the equivalent of the following:

```
 add :railroad_system_id, references(:railroad_systems)
```

Please post:

1. The `create_depos()` function (although for me just using an attributes map instead of a changeset also worked)
2. The full stack trace of the error.
3. Your migrations.